# Timeout error when loading 300 MB file into BigQuery

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery

I followed the Node.js example provided on the loading data post request page (near the bottom here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request), but I’m running into a problem with larger files. The example code works for a .csv of 13 MB, but when I try bigger files, whether 25 MB or 300 MB, it doesn’t work. I see the following error:

> events.js:154
>             throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>             ^
>
> ```
> Error: ETIMEDOUT
>     at null._onTimeout (/Users/Hertig/Development/BitDeliver/BigQuery/node_modules/request/request.js:772:15)
>     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
> ```

I thought that this method of loading data would support bigger files. Has anyone else experienced this? Any advice on loading much bigger files (around 400 MB or larger) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When loading big files to BigQuery, the best method is uploading them to Google Cloud Storage first - then tell BigQuery to read them from your gs://bucket/path/file*.